# NestJS - TypeORM - ManyToOne Entity is undefined

Tags: typescript, entity, nestjs, typeorm, many-to-one

I am trying to link to entities `Child` & `Client`

So I have created 2 entities :

```js
// src/children/child.entity.ts

@Entity()
export class Child extends BaseEntity {

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  firstname: string;

  @Column()
  lastname: string;

  @ManyToOne(type => Client, client => client.children, { eager: false })
  client: Client

  @Column()
  clientId: number;
}
```

and

```js
// src/clients/client.entity.ts

@Entity()
export class Client extends BaseEntity {

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  firstname: string;

  @Column()
  lastname: string;

  @OneToMany(type => Child, child => child.client, { eager: true })
  children: Child[];

}
```

I'm able to create a `client` & a `child`. When I get a `client`, I can retrieve all his `children`.

But I am not able to retrieve a `client` with a `child` :

For example, in `children.controller.ts`

[image]

When I visit `http://locahost:3000/children/1/parent`

I got on the console :

[image]

I am really stuck because I don't know how to solve this issue.

Here is `children.module.ts`

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ChildrenController } from './children.controller';
import { ChildrenService } from './children.service';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { ChildRepository } from './child.repository';
import { ClientRepository } from 'src/clients/client.repository';
import { ClientsService } from 'src/clients/clients.service';
import { Client } from 'src/clients/client.entity';

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([ChildRepository, ClientRepository, Client]),
  ],
  controllers: [ChildrenController],
  providers: [ChildrenService, ClientsService]
})
export class ChildrenModule {}
```

Here is `typeorm.config`

```js
import { TypeOrmModuleOptions } from '@nestjs/typeorm';

export const typeOrmConfig: TypeOrmModuleOptions = {
  type: 'postgres',
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 5432,
  username: 'myusername',
  password: '',
  database: 'mydatabase',
  entities: [__dirname + '/../**/*.entity.{js,ts}'],
  synchronize: true,
}
```

**Edit 1 :**

`children.controller.ts`

```js
// src/children/children.controller.ts

@Controller('children')
export class ChildrenController {

  constructor(
    private childrenService: ChildrenService,
    private clientsService: ClientsService
  ) {}

  @Get('/:id')
  async getChild(id: number): Promise<Child> {
    return await this.childrenService.getChild(id);
  }
}
```

`children.service.ts`

```js
// src/children/children.service.ts

@Injectable()
export class ChildrenService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(ChildRepository)
    private childRepository: ChildRepository,
    @InjectRepository(ClientRepository)
    private clientRepository: ClientRepository
  ) {}

  async getChild(id: number): Promise<Child> {
    return await this.childRepository.findOne(id)
  }
}
```

Thanks for you help

Comment: what code contains your `getChild` method?

Comment: I have added the code for getChild to retrieve the child into the database.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems to me that you forgot add `@JoinColumn()` on ManyToOne side of this relation. Try enhance your code in this way

```js
@Entity()
export class Child extends BaseEntity {

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  firstname: string;

  @Column()
  lastname: string;

  @ManyToOne(type => Client, client => client.children, { eager: false })
  @JoinColumn()
  client: Client

  @Column()
  clientId: number;
}
```

Also, pay attention on `eager` parameter. If it set as `true` this relation will be loaded automatically even you didn't require it manually, otherwise you have to specify that you want relation to be loaded.
Try enhance `children.service.ts` like this:

```js
  async getChild(id: number): Promise<Child> {
    return await this.childRepository.findOne(id, {
      relations: ['client']
    })
  }
```

or you can set this relation as `eager` and it will be loaded automatically every time when you load `Child`

```js
  @ManyToOne(type => Client, client => client.children, { eager: true })
  @JoinColumn()
  client: Client
```

Comment: thanks for your answer ! I still have the issue. 
I have a restart the server after the update. Not working
+ I have remove database tables and still not working.

Comment: after you changed database you need generate migration and apply it

Comment: I am sorry but I dont how to proceed it. 
I thought with `synchronize: true` everything will be auto-updated

Comment: You're right about `synchronize: true`. I've added one more advice to my answer, try it

Comment: adding `{ relations: ['client'] }` solved the issue ! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

as @Yevhenii mention, you forgot to add JoinColumn but you have to specify the client column:

```
    @Entity()
export class Child extends BaseEntity {

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  firstname: string;

  @Column()
  lastname: string;

  @ManyToOne(()=> Client, (client) => client.children, { eager: false })
  @JoinColumn([{ name: "clientId", referencedColumnName: "id" }])
  client: Client

  @Column()
  clientId: number;
}
```

Don't hesitate to tell me the result.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. The solution given by Yevhenii is working well.